# Why isn't my GWT web application running properly?

Tags: java, html, xml, gwt

I'm going through the book: GWT in Action.  On chapter I'm working through the very first hello world application.  It's all in development mode.
My issue is that the label in my .java file is not showing up when I open the URL webpage.  There is nothing being displayed versus the Label("Hello World!") appearing.

EDIT:  When at the displayed webpage, I pressed F12 in google chrome to see if I could find anything weird.  Got the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

HelloWorld.gwt.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
    <module>
        <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
        <source path="client" />
        <entry-point class="com.example.gwt.client.HelloWorld"></entry-point>
    </module>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.example.gwt.client;



import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {


        RootPanel.get().add(new Label("Hello World!"));

    }

}
```

HelloWorld.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src=".nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

My console is displaying this after I run it as a web application:

```
[WARN] Server class 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/Qs/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-2.6.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Users/Qs/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0/gwt-2.6.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
```

Comment: The src attribute you show in HelloWorld.html isn't right. It should be something like src="HelloWorld/HelloWorld.nocache.js". What resource was the 404 error saying it couldn't find?

Comment: The nochache.js file was the resoure not found

Comment: @gatkin: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the `rename-to` in your `gwt.xml` as shown below then by default GWT places the generated `nocache.js` under `war` directory by the name of location of `gwt.xml` followed by its name as shown in below snapshot.

```
<module rename-to="xyz">
```

For more info have a look at [gwt-module dtd](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd).

Please have a look [Defining a module and Renaming modules](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml)

---

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. define `rename-to` in `gwt.xml` that is more preferable over second solution

   - gwt.xml

     ```
     <module rename-to="hello">
     ```
   - html

     ```
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="hello/hello.nocache.js"></script>
     ```
2. use default way

   - html

     ```
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.example.gwt.HelloWorld/com.example.gwt.HelloWorld.nocache.js"></script>
     ```

---

Here is a snapshot to make it more clear

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the src attribute of the script tag in HelloWorld.html to

```
src="com.example.gwt.client.HelloWorld/com.example.gwt.client.HelloWorld.nocache.js"
```

If that still doesn't work, run the GWT compiler and look at the files it generates to determine the exact name of the *.nocache.js file.

Comment: Yes it will not work until and unless `rename-to` is defined as `HelloWorld` in `gwt.xml`. Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Braj, that's why I told him to look at the name of the file the GWT compiler generated. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: yes you are right but its second option that I have mentioned in my post but first one is preferable over second.

Comment: `HelloWorld.gwt.xml` is not under `com.example.gwt.client` package. Please check it again.

Comment: @Braj, that's the package name the original poster used.

Comment: Look at your GWT project structure... You are looking at the package of Entry Point Class.